# Scalding MongoDB connector

Tags: mongodb, scalding

I am using Scalding for ETL implementation and I am looking for a simple way to forward Scalding output to MongoDB instead of HDFS.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This was recently [discussed on Twitter](https://twitter.com/colinmarc/status/493084614018494465). It particular, see the [example code](https://gist.github.com/colinmarc/454c34a4b366b41aa939). This, as of this writing to my knowledge, has not been packaged into a ready to use source.